# Android TCP client using socketchannel. How can I set options for it?

Tags: java, android, tcp, socketchannel

I am working on a client for an android device running on android version 4.4.2 and I have found some strange behavior from it. Most likely it is because it is waiting for more data before building a package, but I do not want that so i am trying to set the option TCP_NODELAY. However, there is no such function or variable anywhere to be found.

How do I set the SocketChannel to be in no delay mode? This is my current code for creating the socket channel.

```
sockChannel = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(socket_ip_, socket_port_));
```

I have tried `sockChannel.socket().setTCPNoDelay(true);`, but I have noticed no change. Am I on the right track? Am I missing something?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If that didn't work, the Nagle algorithm wasn't your problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this, I had the correct solution.

`sockChannel.socket().setTCPNoDelay(true);` worked. The reason I didn't see any changes to the behaviour was because someone had changed the name of the app and had forgotten to document that he changed it. Thus I was starting the old program every time.

To access the socket options and functionality you can request the socket by writing `.socket()`.